# Optimization of GROUP BY which contains the grouping rules with OR condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

There is some table `T1` (in the Oracle database) with some fields `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`:

**Upd 0:** Let the types of the above fields be the same.

Suppose, we need to group our table by the following rule:
`A & B & (C | D)`

**Upd 1:**
The `A & B & (C | D)` expression can be transformed to the following expression:

`(A & B & C) | (A & B & D)`.

Thus, to solve this task I have to union two grouping queries for groups `A, B, C` and `A, B, D`:

```
select A, B, C, count(*) 
from T1 
group by A, B, C

  union all

select A, B, D, count(*) 
from T1 
group by A, B, D
```

If the grouping rule will be more complicated: `A & B & (C | D) & (E | F)`, then the solution will be more bulky, because I have to union grouping queries for the following groups:

`A & B & C & E`, `A & B & D & E`, `A & B & C & F`, `A & B & D & F`.

Is there any possibility to optimize such solution?
Or may be there is a better way to solve such tasks?

**Upd 2:**
I used short form of expressions `A & B & (C | D)` and `A & B & (C | D) & (E | F)` to emphasize that they have a common part `A & B`. And I don't want it to be calculated many times.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: You might have a look at [`group by grouping sets`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#grouping_sets) and the related `cube`, `rollup` etc extensions to `group by`. Sample data and results would help.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean:  "Suppose, we need to group our table by the following rule: A & B & (C | D)"?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, please see the updates `Upd1`, `Upd2` in the main question.

Comment: In your query result you cannot see whether it is C or D you are actually showing. Then, `UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL`)  even removes duplicates, so if you have A=1,B=2,C=3,COUNT=4 and A=1,B=2,CD=3,COUNT=4 only once in your result. Not two rows with COUNT=4, not one row with COUNT=8, but one row with COUNT=4. Is all this desired? It doesn't seem likely. And it somehow looks like not only the query, but even your data model may be inappropriate.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thanks for the comment. Indeed, I need `UNION ALL`. The main question has been modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GROUPING SETS` clause can simplify the code and improve the performance of multiple grouping combinations.

### Simpler Code

For an example, let's start with a simple table:

```
create table t1(a number, b number, c number, d number);
insert into t1
select 0,0,0,0 from dual union all
select 1,0,0,0 from dual union all
select 0,1,0,0 from dual union all
select 1,1,0,0 from dual union all
select 0,0,1,0 from dual union all
select 1,0,1,0 from dual union all
select 0,1,1,0 from dual union all
select 1,1,1,0 from dual union all
select 0,0,0,1 from dual union all
select 1,0,0,1 from dual union all
select 0,1,0,1 from dual union all
select 1,1,0,1 from dual union all
select 0,0,1,1 from dual union all
select 1,0,1,1 from dual union all
select 0,1,1,1 from dual union all
select 1,1,1,1 from dual;
```

The below query represents grouping by "A & (B | C)".  (Unlike your example, I'm going to include some empty columns to demonstrate how the grouping works.)

```
select a, b, null c, count(*)
from t1
group by a, b
union all
select a, null b, c, count(*)
from t1
group by a, c;

A   B   C   COUNT(*)
-   -   -   --------
1   0              4
0   0              4
1   1              4
0   1              4
1      0           4
0      0           4
1      1           4
0      1           4
```

Re-writing with `GROUPING SETS` creates the same results as the preceding query:

```
select a, b, c, count(*)
from t1
group by grouping sets((a, b), (a, c));
```

### Better Performance

Running the above queries using `explain plan for ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => 'basic'));` returns the following execution plans.

For the `UNION ALL` version:

```
------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name |
------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL          |      |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY     |      |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |
|   4 |   HASH GROUP BY     |      |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |
------------------------------------
```

For the `GROUPING SETS` version:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                            |
|   1 |  TEMP TABLE TRANSFORMATION               |                            |
|   2 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6787_464CF95 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | T1                         |
|   4 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6788_464CF95 |
|   5 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |                            |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6787_464CF95 |
|   7 |   LOAD AS SELECT (CURSOR DURATION MEMORY)| SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6788_464CF95 |
|   8 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |                            |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6787_464CF95 |
|  10 |   VIEW                                   |                            |
|  11 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | SYS_TEMP_0FD9D6788_464CF95 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `UNION ALL` execution plan reads from the source table once for each different grouping.  The `GROUPING SETS` execution plan only reads from the source table once, stores information in a temporary table, and then reads from that temporary table.

If the query only uses a small subset of the rows, or only a small subset of the columns, the `GROUPING SETS` plan could be significantly faster since it only has to read the full data once.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!